# how do I run a beta and production version of a django-project alongside each other?

Tags: django, nginx, routes, production, beta

What is the recommended way to run a "beta server" alongside the production server for a django project?
I think about setting up a `beta.mydomain.com` alongside `mydomain.com`... Can I just make a second project folder, git pull the beta branch there and run it somehow in nginx? Is it possible to divide the nginx requests this way to two "different" projects?

Comment: You could use gunicorn to create two different instances one for each environment and then use nginx to route to the right server. Of course make sure they are not sharing the same database.

I would though recommend to have a dedicated instance for each, you would normally want to have your production server running in isolation so it is reliable and secure. For example, if there is an issue with your beta server it might ended up bringing your production server along.

Comment: when I offer customers to test the new features in beta mode, I kind of need to have beta connected to the same database, not? I want it to have reliable functionality in production but at the same time test new code with users...

Comment: if you can manage to perform backwards compatible database migrations so both production and beta are in sync with the database, depending of the size of our application (and of course, if your beta features introduce a lot of database changes) that can sometimes be hard to manage.

Comment: ah yes, migrations... didn't think of them... thanks! need to rethink the whole thing...